# DataSnap using AutoInc key and refresh current record only after insert

Tags: delphi, auto-increment, datasnap

I've not been able to find an answer on this anywhere. Using Delphi XE7 with TClientDataSet, DataSnap & SQL Server. I need to insert a record, apply updates and then refresh that record so I can get the Id and assign it to my object. Seems pretty basic requirement, but on the contrary it is proving to be a royal pain.

I've found the obvious stuff on EDN, SO and Dr Bob:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20847

[DataSnap and the autoinc field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253584/datasnap-and-the-autoinc-field)

http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinC0.htm

However these seem to focus on a "Refresh" of the TClientDataSet to re-fetches the entire table/query. Whilst this does actually resolve the Id field itself (good!), it also moves the cursor off the current record which was just inserted and so I'm not able to get the Id and assign it to my object. Also, for performance over HTTP I don't really want to refetch the entire table every time a record is inserted, if there's 10,000 records this will consume too much bandwidth and be ridiculously slow!

Consider the following code:

```
function TRepository<I>.Insert(const AEntity: I): I;
begin
  FDataSet.DisableControls;
  try
    FDataSet.Insert;
    AssignEntityToDataSet(AEntity);  // SET'S ALL THE RELEVANT FIELDS
    FDataSet.Post;
    FDataSet.ApplyUpdates(-1);
    FDataSet.Refresh;  // <--- I tried RefreshRecord here but it cannot resolve the record
    AEntity.Id := FDataSet.FieldByName('Id').AsInteger; // <----- THIS NOW POINTS TO WRONG ROW
  finally
    FDataSet.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I need to be able to refresh and stay on the current record otherwise I do not know the Id of the record just created and the GUI cannot stay focused on the current record.

Hopefully something obvious I'm missing.

Cheers.
Rick.

Comment: I used to provide this information in the DataSetProvider.AfterApplyUpdates.  You can assign it to a OwnerData argument in that event, then read it back again after you've called ApplyUpdates.  That is assuming you're able to retrieve the info at the point.  I used to return the ID as part of the Insert SQL statement.

Comment: Assuming this event on the client: ClientDataSetAfterApplyUpdates(Sender: TObject; var OwnerData: OleVariant) how would I get that data in there? I assume I need to have something returned from the DataSnap Server? Not sure how to do that?

Comment: Ok, so I figured out how to return some user OwnerData from the Provider.AfterApplyUpdates. However I don't have access to my object when that event fires. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can get hands on the new ID inside the `AfterUpdateRecord` event of your DataProvider, your event handler then may look like this (the current record of DeltaDS is the one just inserted into SourceDS):

```
  if (UpdateKind = ukInsert) then begin
    DeltaDS.FindField('Id').NewValue := <TheNewID>;
  end;
```

Make sure to have the `poPropogateChanges` option set in the provider. This will transfer the changed *Id* field back to the ClientDataSet.

Now you can get rid of the `FDataSet.Refresh` call.

Comment: Thanks Uwe. I can get the NewValue returning to the client from the DeltaDS, however I cannot find a way to get the new Id after the INSERT? I'm using MSSQL hooked up to TFDQuery component, however it does not appear to be populating the TFDAutoIncField. I assume that it uses some kind of auto-generated SQL INSERT statement for the new records. For example, when using a TFDUpdateSQL component, it seems to do a "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as Id, *" immediately after the INSERT statement, but I don't know how to get that Identity value. Any ideas on how to get this value?

Comment: After further testing, it is not possible to get the SCOPE_IDENTITY() of a row during the AfterUpdateRecord event since the INSERT transaction does not fall out of scope until the end of the TDataSetProvider.InternalApplyUpdates method when "if FTransactionStarted then (DataSet as IProviderSupportNG).PSEndTransaction(Commit) " is executed. So I will need to find another way to do this, possible in the AfterApplyUpdates, but this only gives me access to the OwnerData variable, not the DeltaDS. This is proving to be both tricky and time consuming.

Comment: Have you tried setting ResolveToDataSet in the DataSetProvider? This should let the FDQuery make the job of the insertion and thus should update the autoinc field of the FDQuery.

Comment: I turned on the ResolveTo DataSet and it was still not working. However I then changed the TFDAutoIncField to a TIntegerField and set the AutogenerateValue to AutoInc and this populates the SourceDS which I then assigned to the DeltaDS. So it is working finally. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does allow you to get the last identity it generated in several ways - there's no need to "refresh" the record/query which means re-issuing a SELECT and can generate undesiderable side-effects. You can use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() or use an OUTPUT clause. If the Delphi database driver supports it, TField.AutogenerateValue should accomplish that task automatically (see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TField.AutoGenerateValue)

Otherwise you have to put that new data into your delta (see Raabe answer - this has to be done on the datasnap server which actually talks to the database) after reading it, so it's sent back to the client. You also need to set properly and TField.ProviderFlags to ensure data are applied correctly (see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Influencing_How_Updates_Are_Applied), usually you don't want those field appear in an UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks LDS. I know how to get the last updated Id, however the insert statement seems to be handled internally by the TFDQuery component. I tried using the TFDAutoIncField as suggested too, but cannot get this to work either. I feel that I'm close, but I'm missing something. The lack of good documentation and working examples make this very frustrating indeed. Any further ideas?

Comment: Often with Datasnap I found that the "automatic" management of database access is not flexible enough, and I prefer to handle it in the provider events. It means to write more code, but I have full control of what queries are sent to the database, and I can handle the outcome and send back proper data to the client dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your help. A combination of Uwe's suggestions with yours about the AutoInc field solved the issue.

Comment: Are you able to share some examples of how you handle deletes/updates in the Provider events? I'm struggling at the moment with getting more complex queries working. It seems that with ResolveToDataSet turned on, the UPDATE/DELETE methods do not work and trying to figure out how to handle this is insane. Any ideas or help would be awesome.